# Как просмотреть список созданных пулов адресов на маршрутизаторе Cisco?

Tags: cisco, cisco-packet-tracer

В рамках лабораторной работы по компьютерным сетям в Cisco Packet Tracer нужно настроить маршрутизатор в качестве DHCP-сервера. Делается это командой **ip dhcp pool pool_name**, и дальше настраиваются его параметры.

А если мне в руки попала чужая симуляция в Tracer или живой роутер? Я так и не смог найти, как посмотреть уже выделенные на нём пулы адресов и их настройки. Только уже выданные адреса командой **show ip dhcp binding**. При этом пул можно удалить **no ip dhcp pool pool_name**, но не хранят же список имен пулов на бумажке.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Делается это командой **show ip dhcp pool** в привилегированном режиме.